# How can I avoid ProjectionException when reprojecting a WMS Layer

Tags: geotools

I'm using Geotools to develop a GIS Java application using Swing. I'm using a JPanel to render a WMS Map (which is in a local geoserver). I'm able to switch between two different map : A WGS84 Pseudo Mercator Map and a WGS84 Geographic Lon/Lat Map, and to display a 10° Square grid that is projected with the Map.
I'm able to reproject those maps (and grid) in three differents projections : WGS84 Lon/Lat, WGS84 Pseudo Mercator, and Lambert 93 projection.
All of which works, except when I try to project the Pseudo Mercator Map to WGS84 Lon/Lat with the grid enabled.
When the Grid is disabled, I "only" get a ProjectionException from StreamingRenderer saying "Latitude 120° is too close to Pole".
When it is enabled I get two ProjectionException, and my grid/map aren't projected properly (and not rendered properly).

Here is my Map Initialization :

```java
private void initMap()
{
  if (mapContent != null) mapContent.dispose();
  if (mapContent == null) mapContent = new MapContent();

  mapContent.setTitle(selectedLayer.getTitle());

  mapContent.getViewport().setMatchingAspectRatio(true);
  mapContent.getViewport().setFixedBoundsOnResize(false);
  WMSLayer wmsLayer = new WMSLayer(wms, selectedLayer);

  ReferencedEnvelope dataBounds = wmsLayer.getBounds();
  CoordinateReferenceSystem dataCrs = dataBounds.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();

  mapContent.addLayer(wmsLayer);

  mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(new Rectangle(getWidth(), getHeight()));
  mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(dataBounds);
  mapContent.setVisible(true);

  FatureLayer gridLayer = initGridLayer();
  mapContent.addLayer(gridLayer);
}
```

My Grid initialization :

```java
public FeatureLayer initGridLayer()
{
  SimpleFeatureCollection lonLatGrid = null;
  Style defaultStyle = null;

  try {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem lonLatCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
    ReferencedEnvelope lonLatEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(mapContent.getViewport().getBounds().transform(lonLatCRS, false));
    SimpleFeatureSource grid = Grids.createSquareGrid(lonLatEnvelope, 10.0);
    lonLatGrid = grid.getFeatures();
    
    lonLatGrid = new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(lonLatGrid, mapContent.getViewport().getBounds().getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    defaultStyle = SLD.createSimpleStyle(lonLatGrid.getSchema());

  } catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
  }

  return new FeatureLayer(lonLatGrid, defaultStyle, "gridLayer");
}
```

And my reprojection function :

```java
public void reproject(CoordinateReferenceSystem newCrs)
{
  initMap();

  if (newCrs.getName().equals(mapContent.getCoordinateReferenceSystem().getName()))
  {
     drawLayers(true);
     return;
  }

  if (!CRS.isCompatible(newCrs, mapContent.getReferenceSystem(), newCrs, false) || CRS.getEnvelope(newCrs) == null)
  {
    // Log Error
    return;
  }

  ReferencedEnvelope newEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(CRS.getEnvelope(newCrs));

  mapContent.getViewport().setBonds(newEnvelope);
  mapContent.getViewport().setCoordinateReferenceSystem(newCrs);

  drawLayers(true);

}
```

All of the Above Function are in a JMapFrame Geotools/Swing Component.

Here are the logs :

```java
java.lang.Exception: Error transforming bbox
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1193) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2313) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2251) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°33.2'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:207) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:879) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°33.2'S is too close to a pole.

    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:926) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:219) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1483) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.EnvelopeReprojector.transform(EnvelopeReprojector.java:92) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1547) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:653) ~[gt-main-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1175) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted

2023-02-22 14:58:53.824 ERROR 113434 --- [pool-3-thread-1] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Error transforming bbox

java.lang.Exception: Error transforming bbox
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1193) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2313) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2251) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°33.2'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:207) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:879) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:926) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:219) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1483) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.EnvelopeReprojector.transform(EnvelopeReprojector.java:92) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1547) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:653) ~[gt-main-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1175) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted

2023-02-22 14:58:53.825  WARN 113434 --- [pool-3-thread-1] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Got a tranform exception while trying to de-project the current envelope, bboxs intersect therefore using envelope)

org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°33.2'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:207) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:879) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:926) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:219) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1483) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.EnvelopeReprojector.transform(EnvelopeReprojector.java:92) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1547) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:653) ~[gt-main-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1175) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2313) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2251) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]

2023-02-22 14:58:53.829 ERROR 113434 --- [pool-3-thread-1] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Error querying layer

java.lang.Exception: Error transforming bbox
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1193) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2313) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2251) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°50.8'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:207) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:879) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:926) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:219) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1483) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.EnvelopeReprojector.transform(EnvelopeReprojector.java:92) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1547) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:653) ~[gt-main-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1175) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°50.8'S is too close to a pole.


2023-02-22 14:58:53.830 ERROR 113434 --- [pool-3-thread-1] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Error transforming bbox

java.lang.Exception: Error transforming bbox
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1193) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2313) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2251) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°50.8'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:207) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:879) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:926) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:219) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1483) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.EnvelopeReprojector.transform(EnvelopeReprojector.java:92) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1547) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:653) ~[gt-main-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1175) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted

2023-02-22 14:58:53.868  WARN 113434 --- [pool-3-thread-1] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Got a tranform exception while trying to de-project the current envelope, bboxs intersect therefore using envelope)

org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 121°50.8'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:207) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:879) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:926) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:219) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1483) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.EnvelopeReprojector.transform(EnvelopeReprojector.java:92) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1547) ~[gt-referencing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:653) ~[gt-main-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1175) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2313) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2251) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917) ~[gt-render-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:38) ~[gt-swing-27.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

PsuedoMercator is pretty much undefined above/below 85 degrees of latitude so I suspect your map is going to the poles and the reprojection algorithm is upset about the infinities.

An alternative is that you've switched lat/lon to lon/lat (or vise a versa) at some point and your map is 180 degrees tall and 90 degrees wide.

To be able to tell which is the problem you need to check what the value of `newEnvelope` is.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer ! I just saw that newEnvelope is {-180, 180, -90, 90} so I think it is the first option. Is there a way to get definition bounds of a CRS so I can create the largest Envelope ?